# Validating NServiceBus Event Properties (Using Interfaces)

Tags: nservicebus

I am not able to validate the event published using NServiceBus.Testing ( NServiceBus, V6 beta)

In my api controller I publish an event

```
await _messageSession.Publish<IStrategyCreated>(stgy =>
{
     stgy.StrategyId = strategyToAdd.Id;
     stgy.InvestmentObjective = strategyToAdd.InvestmentObjective;
     stgy.PrincipalInvestmentStrategy = strategyToAdd.PrincipalInvestmentStrategy;
     stgy.PortfolioConsultant = strategyToAdd.PortfolioConsultant;
     stgy.StrategyName = strategyToAdd.Name;
     stgy.StrategyCode = strategyToAdd.Code;
});
```

In my test I have:

```
Assert.That(messageSession.PublishedMessages.Length, Is.EqualTo(1), "Messages published");
Assert.IsInstanceOf<IStrategyCreated>(messageSession.PublishedMessages[0],"Message published was of type IStrategyCreated");
```

The second line fails, because the message type is `IStrategyCreated_impl`
Error:

```
  Message published was of type IStrategyCreated
  Expected: instance of <Strategy.Contracts.Events.IStrategyCreated>
  But was:  <NServiceBus.Testing.PublishedMessage`1[System.Object]>
```

Full test Method:

```
    public async Task TestCreateStrategy ()
    {

        var messageSession = new TestableMessageSession();
        var dbContent = _container.Resolve<IStrategyDbContext>();
        var apiContext = new StrategyController(messageSession, dbContent);
        var result =
            await apiContext.Create(new StrategyModel {Code = "NEW"}) as
                OkNegotiatedContentResult<StrategyModel>;

        Assert.That(messageSession.PublishedMessages.Length, Is.EqualTo(1), "Messages published");
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<IStrategyCreated>(messageSession.PublishedMessages[0],"Message published was of type IStrategyCreated");
        var stgyCreated =(IStrategyCreated) messageSession.PublishedMessages[0];

        Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null, "Result Is Null");
        Assert.That(stgyCreated.StrategyCode, Is.EqualTo("NEW"));
        Assert.That(result?.Content.Code, Is.EqualTo("NEW"), "Returning Strategy");
        Assert.That(dbContent.Strategies.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1), "Exactly 1 item was added to strategy list");


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `messageSession.PublishedMessages[0]` use `messageSession.PublishedMessages[0].Message`, should work then.